Is there a known neurological/psychological basis for the perception of resolution with descending perfect fifth motion?
Some neurological phenomena in music are relatively well understood, such as rhythmic entrainment and the perception of consonance and dissonance. However, I am not as familiar with any studies or research into the origins of perception surrounding functional harmony.
One of the most fundamental components of western functional harmony is the tendency toward perfect fifth relationships between subsequent chords, generally ordered as descending perfect fifths in the standard harmonic progression. Of course, other chord motions are frequently used, but they are usually considered deviations from the default harmonic changes. As we get closer to modern music, this progression is even less of an expectation, but I imagine even in the tonal music of today, the most common chord change is V-I.
This leads back to the original question: can the tendency toward descending fifth progressions be attributed to some neurological or psychological phenomenon? Is this simply a western invention and preference that we have been enculturated into? If it has a physiological root, we would expect it to occur simultaneously across many cultures, though most musical cultures did not develop complex systems of harmony. Of course perfect fifths themselves are ubiquitous, but I am more concerned with harmonic motion and progression rather than simultaneous harmonies.
I am interested primarily in scholarly sources on the subject, if anyone knows of any.
Thank you!

I think the premise is just not true. While fifths as a concept are extremely common across traditions worldwide, and this can be explained with basic physics, the notion that the V-I resolution is particularly strong or even "the resolution" is specific to the music descended from medieval European music.

@leftaroundabout I did allude to that, but I'm curious if you have any more knowledge on the subject. I'm not just talking about V-I, but the entire "standard harmonic progression" of the common practice period (viid-iii-vi-ii-V-I). Many traditions based on modes can be understood by building scales off stacked fifths (whether or not that is the best way to analyze them), even if they don't have music with harmonic progressions. There are many patterns which emerge from the circle of fifths that it just seems wrong to me to ascribe it to coincidence, which is why I asked this question.

"There are many patterns which emerge from the circle of fifths that it just seems wrong to me to ascribe it to coincidence": are there, though?  The "microtonal" scales that appear in some nonwestern traditions aren't readily obtained from the circle of fifths, and the difference between the Pythagorean approximation for a given interval and the true tuning of that interval is, in some cases, significant.  The main reason diatonic scales can be approximated by the circle of fifths is that the intervals between adjacent elements are mostly close to 1/6 or 1/12 of an octave.

I suspect the lack of studies is because much of what you describe is not a human phenomenon but a Western one; the V-I resolution feels as strong as it does because it's ubiquitous in Western culture, not because there is a specific neurological basis for it.
What you might find, however, is that there could be a neurological basis for our feeling of tonic, or the ending tone/home tone of a melody.  This is easier to believe because many many cultures around the world include the notion of a total center.  And if there is a neurological basis for that, there could be a neurological explanation for us "wanting" a melody to end on the tonic.
Which brings us to your question. If instead of finding a basis for the V-I progression you sought to find an explanation for why we feel a "pull" from re to do, you might get further.  And as an extension of that, we could view the V-I resolution as a strengthening structure built to reinforce the melodic descent. Look into Schenker analysis for more about the importance of melodic resolution and its support through harmony.
This is largely conjecture.

But if there are no studies, how do we know this? That is why I am asking if anyone knows of any literature that addresses this subject.

@LandryPierce how do we know what?  That there is a "pull" from V to I or from re to do or from si to do or anywhere else?  We know it because it is a subjective phenomenon and people have told us that they experience it.  How do we know that we are supposed to say "is there a basis" rather than "are there a basis"?  Language is learned.  How do we explain that some people love brown and gold curtains and others hate them?  Taste is learned.  Not every aspect of perception is amenable to an objective psychoneurological explanation.

@LandryPierce An analogy to your question might to ask whether there have been neurological/psychological studies about literary structures. Rising action, falling action, cyclic storytelling, flashbacks, Rashomon-style presentation, narrative in verse, metaphor, alliteration—all these are cultural conventions practiced at various times. We could study the impact of them on a reader's physiological state as they read, but we should be careful to understand this as a medical metric within a sociological inquiry. I.e., not "do these physiological findings tell us that...

... that the narrative device in question has a connection to something universal in human physiognomy," but rather "for a reader enculturated to expect this from their narrative, how can we gain greater insight on what it does for them." And I doubt there are many such studies simply because of all the things research dollars can be spent on, "this is your brain on a deceptive cadence" isn't high on the list of grants. (Don't get me wrong, there is a lot of research on the overlap between music and neurology, though I doubt much of it focuses on specific music-theory elements.)

@LandryPierce, I don't think you need scientific study to make the cultural point. Music theory already allows us to see how various harmonic styles "contradict" each other regarding functional harmony and musical experience. In other words, functional harmony is not universal and we already know this.


...psychological phenomenon? Is this simply a western invention and preference that we have been enculturated into?

I think it is cultural, but not necessarily western only.
So people will point to the harmonic overtone sequence and say it supports the musical importance of the perfect fifth. Linking the overtone sequence with harmonic style has been debunked by others, and I personally do not find it convincing, and certainly not much support for triadic chord progressions.
Some people talk about the "pull" of the half steps in the dominant to tonic relationship, the TI to DO and FA to MI movements. Certainly those half steps are important, but I think this also is cultural rather than a physical phenomena. If it really was a matter of half steps, then mixing major and minor triads (V i, iv I) or diminished dominants (viio7 I) should be "stronger" than two major triads (V I) but that is not the case.

Of course perfect fifths themselves are ubiquitous, but I am more concerned with harmonic motion and progression rather than simultaneous harmonies.

I think you are right to make that distinction. Harmonic motion, specifically functional harmony is a stylistic element, and style is cultural.
Consider two ubiquitous progressions the classical/jazz pattern ii V I and "blues" turnaround V IV I. The former is a roots by descending fifth pattern while the latter would be considered a retrogression (a sort of aberrant progression) ...but only in the stylistic sense of functional harmony. In other harmonic styles (rock, blues, etc.) the root by descending step of V VI is perfectly solid harmony.
The perfect fifth aspect that applies to both of those styles is the vertical harmonic relationships of the triads, especially when considering the relative "strength" and "stability" of those chords in root position. There is some physical support to that element in the acoustics of the overtone series. But when that perfect fifth gets applied to functional root progressions it enters a realm of style and culture.

This leads back to the original question: can the tendency toward descending fifth progressions be attributed to some neurological or psychological phenomenon?

One final thought, which may be a stretch, but I think is worth mentioning, is about harmonic sequence and melodic direction.
When you follow basic voice leading through a descending fifth progression, the overall melodic direction is descending. By comparison the melodic direct of ascending fifths is ascending.
I expect material can be found about the psychology of high/low or ascending/descending pitch. Of course the problem for functional harmony as a supposed physical phenomena is you can have the same ascending or descending melodic motions regardless of any notion of chord roots.
